# way of writing for dotnet 3.5 quick and dirty async method

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

In my C# code I am calling some tracking services by using (apparently) inefficient 3rd party libraries.
the problem is that they are blocking my thread and the user get some lags.

I want to wrap all the calling to this 3rd parties in an async method.
What is the best and easiest way to achieve it?
I don't need any response from this call, I just want to remove it from the main thread..

Is there a quick and dirty solution?
Maybe something like `setTimeOut(function(){/*code here*/},1)` in JavaScript?

I am searching for a solution for some time, but dot net 3.5 not supporting the simple and fast async approaches.

Comment: Have a look at Task and TaskFactory, they have a very low overhead and are easy to create / chain / wait / handle exception, etc...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782519(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks GameAlchemist but your answer is relevant for .net  4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways in .NET to write multithreaded code. Jon Skeet covered some of them in this blog post: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/

So the idea here is to spawn a new thread (or use a thread from the thread pool) to execute the slow code inside. This way the main thread won't be blocked.

Comment: Thanks, but I want a quick and dirty solution. 
more over, do I need to close the thread or it closes it self? because I'll open a lot of threads here..

Comment: Sure, what's not quick and dirty about `new Thread(() => { /* code here */ }).Start();`? Seems pretty easy. You don't need to be closing a thread. It will stop automatically when your code finishes executing. You don't have to worry about that.

Comment: by the way is there a way to give the thread a name in this approach?
something like "new Thread(('thread1') => { /* code here */ }).Start();"???

Comment: Sure: `var thread = new Thread(() => { /* code here */ }); thread.Name = "SomeName"; thread.Start();`.